# BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy)

Tags: android

```
    I try to implement Connection between two devices(Any ios/Android)    and transfer text using BLE

    I try too many demos from GitHub and also try from documentation step by step but I am not getting a success

    some time give Error like :

    > GATT server 133

    or

    >android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID)'    on a null object reference

    Please help me

    Thank you so much

    Here is the my two activity code one ble class and one activity  to call function from BLE claass

    I want just pass small text to android to android or android to ios using ble

    please help I tried from too many days

================================================================
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> getDevicess;
    List<BluetoothDevice> getConnectedDevicess;
    TextView tvscan;
    TextView tvConnected;
    TextView tvsend;
    Ble ble;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvsend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsend);
        getDevicess = new ArrayList<>();
        getConnectedDevicess = new ArrayList<>();
        ble = new Ble(this, getApplicationContext(), "zad");
        ble.enableBle();
        ble.checkPermission(0);
        ble.scanLeDevice(true, 1000);

   //after scan and connect click on send button then give error
        tvsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ble.writeCharacteristics(hexStringToByteArray("abcdefg"), UUID.fromString("fffffff0-00f7-4000-b000-000000000000"), UUID.fromString("fffffff5-00f7-4000-b000-000000000000"));

            }
        });
    }

    public byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length()-1;
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }

        return data;
    }
}


===========================================BLE CLass==================
```

// Function To Write Characteristics .. !
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    public void writeCharacteristics(byte[] data, UUID DLE_SERVICE, UUID DLE_WRITE_CHAR) {
        BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(DLE_SERVICE);
        if (Service == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "service not found!");
            //return false;
        }

```
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic charc1 = Service.getCharacteristic(DLE_WRITE_CHAR);
    if (charc1 == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "char not found!");
        Log.d(TAG, "CHARAC_-TRST" + charc1.getUuid());
        // return false;
    }
    // charc1.setValue(new byte[]{0x00, 0x05, 0x10, 0x01, 0x3E, 0x01, 0x23});

    charc1.setValue(data);
    boolean stat = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(charc1);

    Log.d(TAG, "FINISHED WRITTING CHAR 1 status write :(status)" + stat);

    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
        for (byte byteChar : data)
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));


    }


}
```

Comment: Please, give more details about what is happening and what isn't working.

Comment: I am getting ble device list
and also connect two devices but i am going to send some text then it gives error

Comment: You probably need to add more information, instead of the "wall of code". People won't help you if they need to spend too much time trying to understand what is wrong with your code. Try editing your question with specific information and error messages clearly pointing out to what the issue is.

Comment: i am facing this two error when i call writeCharacteristics() function--> GATT server 133

   or

   --> android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID)'    on a null object reference

Comment: now I put some small code, before for easy understanding i put whole code thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is problematic:

```
   public void displayBleService(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
       Log.d(TAG, "display Services");
       List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
       for (BluetoothGattService services : gattServices) {
           Log.d(TAG, "SERVICES == ." + services.getUuid());

           characteristics = services.getCharacteristics();
           for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
               Log.d(TAG, "CAHRACTERISTICS  == ." + characteristic.getUuid() + "--" + characteristic.getProperties());


               //enableNotification(characteristic, true);
           }
       }

   }
```

the `services` is null, and thus the `services.getCharacteristics()` is provoking the NPE.

Please debug your code, and make sure you have `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission as well. Feel free to add necessary null-guards as well at your own discretion.

Comment: i am  getting CHARACTERISTICS  Properly but when i going to call writeCharacteristics then it give error like : 
  android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID)'    on a null object reference  

and this error come from defaukt blluetooth class